No class.getModule() in Android/Java?
In Android Studio Ladybug it's not possible to compile a call to class.getModule() method, for example String.class.getModule() leads to build error: cannot find symbol .getModule.
Is it somehow linked to this answer?
The root problem: In my Android app I am trying to use the XML parser that transforms data in an XML file into a collection of instances of certain classes. That library eventually calls SomeClass.class.getModule() and my app crashes at that point. Then I noticed I can't even call String.class.getModule() in Android app whereas I can do it in plain Java (version 17 or 21 btw).
So, is it possible to call class.getModule() in an Android app?

You've already got an answer below from ianhanniballake, but to elaborate a bit, Android tends to lag behind the full Java language.  Java and Android are two different things, made by different companies, and those companies don't always keep up with each other's developments.  I don't know when or if Android plans to have a module or similar environment, it might be quite a while I think.

(No it is not related to that answer.)

Android supports a subset of Java APIs. Although Android 14 is up to Java 17, and getModule was added in Java 9, it doesn't seem to be in that subset.

As seen on the documentation for Android's Class, there is indeed no getModule() method available on any version of Android.
